# Django Celery Error Message Cannot Serialize

Tags: python, django, django-views, celery

I keep getting this error message when I run my script on my Djano App. (Object of type WSGIRequest is not JSON serializable) when I have my serializer set to JSON. If i change it to Pickle, I get this error message. (cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object). I have spent days on this trying to figure out how to fix this. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Here is my script im sending to celery.

```
def ImportSchools(request):
    print("Getting school data from SIS")
    url = ""
    payload = {}
    token = APIInformation.objects.get(api_name="PowerSchool")
    key = token.key
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(key)}   
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
    encode_xml = response.text.encode('utf8')
    pretty_xml = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(encode_xml)
    pretty_xml_str = pretty_xml.toprettyxml()
    xml_string = ET.fromstring(encode_xml)
    schools = xml_string.findall("school")
    for school in schools:
      psid = school.find("id").text
      name = school.find("name").text
      school_number = school.find("school_number").text
      low_grade = school.find("low_grade").text
      high_grade = school.find("high_grade").text
    
      if not School.objects.filter(schoolpsid=psid):
        print("Record doesn't exist in DB, creating record.")  
        x = School.objects.create(schoolpsid=psid, school_name=name, school_number=school_number, low_grade=low_grade, high_grade=high_grade)
        x.save()
      elif School.objects.filter(schoolpsid=psid).exists():
        print("Record exists in DB, updating record.")
        School.objects.filter(schoolpsid=psid).update(school_name=name, school_number=school_number, low_grade=low_grade, high_grade=high_grade)
    print("School Data Pull Complete")    
    return("Done")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution of this was to remove request as an argument and it fixed the issue.